# Double Click on from date change the to date also in Date range datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When i double click on from date in Date range datepicker,the to date date is getting changed as well.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my jsfiddle:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50fa9s1m/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8907#no1

> What happens is that calling a method on datepicker 2 while datepicker 1 is open causes datepicker 2 to be rendered in place of datepicker 1. You can see this happening by selecting a date in a different month for datepicker 2, then selecting a date in datepicker 1; you'll see the month switch as the datepicker is closing.

But if you use a timeout, all things are right! See on jsfiddle.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );}, 100);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7x0pwtxf/

Comment: although it's a bit late for this answer, but thanks, it's really working!!